# How to count the datawindow computed fields dynamically?

Tags: powerbuilder

Dynamically how to count the datawindow computed fields and DDDW Fields? is there any functions in PowerBuilder?
otherwise we need to take DW Syntax? then parsing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to start with a dw.Describe ("datawindow.objects") to get a tab delimited list of all objects on the DataWindow's UI surface. Parse apart this list, then for each do a dw.Describe (as_ObjName + ".type") and test for the value "compute".

Good luck,

Terry.